# Most efficient way to communicate through wifi

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-wifi

I was wondering what is the most efficient way to communicate between an android application and a java software on a computer through wifi.
I used rmi by sending signal every 10 seconds to know if my devices are still connected to rmi server on my computer.

But the main problem is that use RMI to communicate is not really efficient and when many devices try to communicate with the computer I got some timeout exception because my access point can't handle all data send.

That's why I tried to find the less data consuming to communicate and know when devices are connected or not to my application. (I probably can still use RMI for punctual action but send an RMI packet every 10 seconds is probably not the best way)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct Socket connection. Of course you'll need to come up with some sort of application level protocol there, since otherwise you're just sending bytes from one place to another.

For example, you could have the first byte tell the type of the message, and the second byte (or short) the size of a payload. Then you could send messages up to 256 (or 65536) bytes to the server and pretty much do what you want.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but can I be sure that rmi communication will be available if my bytes sending works. I mean, do you is there some case where my bytes could work and communication through rmi not ?

Comment: Well, RMI is Java specific, and in my opinion a bit outdated. It's essentially Java's own RPC implementation, so if your server ever changes to a non-java implementation, you'll be in trouble.

Comment: I did exactly what we said before and it works much more better but I still have some connections issues. I set socket timeout at 1000ms and have some socket timeout exception, do you think it's normal ? Increase socket timeout would be an answer ?

Comment: Yea, set socket timeout to 30 secs or even remove it completely.

Comment: @Substitut, could you help me out also? I have similar case here: https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/247000/wifi-communication-between-two-device-without-intermediary-device